# Index outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, asp.net

During local my system its working but when i uploaded it on-site i encountered problem..
Do i need some dll?

> Index was outside the bounds of the array.
>     Exception Details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

```
Line 6:      if (Request.Params["mode"] != null) Mode = Request.Params["mode"];
Line 7:      if (!Path.Split('/')[3].Equals("Default.aspx") && (String)Session["accesslevel"] == ("0"))
```

Comment: Can you show us, what you have in path ?

Comment: http://philmont.com.ph/backend/default.aspx

Comment: can you change your condition to if (!Path.Split('/')[2].Equals("Default.aspx")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I had to guess I'd say it's probably this:

```
Path.Split('/')[3]
```

If you're running under http://localhost/myapp you'll have more elements in the array after calling Path.Split than if you are running under http://www.myapp.com. Chances are you only have 3 elements in that array in production, not the 4 you probably have in dev.

**EDIT:**

For the page you posted, a call to Request.Path is going to return:

```
"/backend/default.aspx"
```

When you do a split on '/', you're only going to get back 3 elements:

```
[0] = ""
[1] = "backend"
[2] = "default.aspx"
```

That's why `Path.Split('/')[3]` will throw an `IndexOutOfRangeException`. So the short answer is you should switch it to `Path.Split('/')[2]` in production, but a better solution would be to come up with a way where the case is handled using the same code in both environments.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in this condition; `if (!Path.Split('/')[3].Equals("Default.aspx")` This might be the reason the server path will not be like it is on your localhost.

Replace this `if (!Path.Split('/')[3].Equals("Default.aspx")`
with

```
if (!Path.Split('/')[2].Equals("Default.aspx")
```

Answer (score 2):

I think problem is here `Path.Split('/')[3]`, length of array is smaller than 4.

Answer (score 1):

The Path.Split seems to be the problem.  Why not use the Uri class to parse the url.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
if (!Path.Split('/')[3].Equals("Default.aspx") && (String)Session["accesslevel"] == ("0"))
```

use this:

```
Path.SubString(Path.LastIndexOf('/')).Equals("Default.aspx") .....
```